# How to make a content in the middle of the Table for tabular

Tags: tables, tabulary

I am not very good in having a table in LaTex. I just try to reused some table format.

How to make the "circle" content in the middle. My table looks very weird.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx,
            threeparttable, tabulary}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h!]
% \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1.0em}
\centering

\begin{threeparttable} 
\sisetup{table-format=13.0, table-number-alignment=center, table-column-width=1.0cm}
 \begin{tabular}{lSS}
    %  \toprule
    % %   \addlinespace[1.2ex]
    %  \multirow{2.4}{*}{\textbf{Stimulus Number\tnote{a}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Classification Accuracy (\%)}}\\ 
     
     \toprule
     \textbf{Stimulus Number\tnote{a}} & \textbf{Classification Accuracy (\%)} \\ 
     
    %  \cmidrule{2-3}
    % &{\textbf{Accuracy}}
    %  & {\textbf{Inaccuracy}} \\
     \midrule
    Stimulus 1 (A21, B32; A11) &  68.42  \\
    Stimulus 2 (A2, B47; A1)  &   94.74 \\
    Stimulus 3 (A6, B40; B51)  &  84.21    \\


 \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \footnotesize 
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] Stimulus Number (Class A Sample Numbers, Class B Sample Numbers; Reference X Sample Numbers)
\end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable} 
\end{table}   


\end{document}
```

Comment: on compiling the above code the contents are `centered` and not left aligned as you point out

Comment: Off-topic: The `\caption` statement should be included in the `threeparttable` environment. (The three formal parts of a `threeparttable` environment are the caption, the tabular-type data structure, and the `tablenotes` environment.) I've noticed that you've edited your query and deleted the `\caption` statement, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Remark*, added 2021-08-16: The answer shown below addresses the OP's question *as originally asked*. In the meantime, though, the OP appears to have modified the query significantly, with uncertain consequences for what's expected in terms of an answer.)

Observe that the table has 2, not 3, columns. The `siunitx` option `table-format=13.0` is not appropriate for the data in column 2; it should be `table-format=3.2`. The option `table-column-width=1.0cm` seems inappropriate as well; I would definitely omit that option. Finally, I believe that `table-number-alignment=center` may be omitted as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for 'S' column type

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable} 
\caption{Classification accuracy for \textit{Pilot Study}}
    \label{tab:Classification Accuracy_for_Pilot_Study}
    
\begin{tabular}{@{} l S[table-format=3.2] @{}}
    \toprule
    Stimulus Number\tnote{a} & {Classification Accuracy (\%)} \\ 
    \midrule
    Stimulus  1 (A21, B32; A11) &  68.42 \\
    Stimulus  2 (A2, B47; A1)   &  94.74 \\
    Stimulus  3 (A6, B40; B51)  &  84.21 \\
    Stimulus  4 (A5, B32; A4)   & 100.00 \\
    Stimulus  5 (A16, B49; B50) & 100.00 \\
    Stimulus  6 (A7, B36; B37)  &  84.21 \\
    Stimulus  7 (A20, B38; A21) & 100.00 \\ 
    Stimulus  8 (A29, B45; B46) & 100.00 \\
    Stimulus  9 (A24, B43; A26) & 100.00 \\
    Stimulus 10 (A11, B50; B51) &  94.74 \\ 
    Stimulus 11 (A8, B35; B36)  & 100.00 \\
    Stimulus 12 (A10, B42; B43) & 100.00 \\
    Stimulus 13 (A8, B32; A10)  & 100.00 \\
    Stimulus 14 (A18, B34; B35) &  89.47 \\ 
    Stimulus 15 (A3, B47; A23)  &  94.74 \\
    Stimulus 16 (A13,  B38; A14)&  84.21 \\
    Stimulus 17 (A18, B43; A21) &  68.42 \\
    Stimulus 18 (A7, B40; B42)  &  84.21 \\ 
    Stimulus 19 (A23, B47; A24) &  94.74 \\
    Stimulus 20 (A8, B55; B56)  &  89.47 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\footnotesize 
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] Stimulus Number (Class A Sample Numbers, Class B Sample Numbers; Reference X Sample Numbers)
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable} 
\end{table}   

\end{document}
```

Comment: how come I get it centered with original code of the OP -- added the output as an answer below -- only for educational purpose

Comment: @jsbibra - The OP's code has *multiple* issues. The incorrect `table-format` option is just one of them. Another one, which I didn't bother to highlight, is the option `table-column-width=1.0cm`.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx,
            threeparttable, tabulary}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h!]
% \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1.0em}
\centering
\caption{Classification accuracy for \textit{Pilot Study}}
    \label{tab:Classification Accuracy for Pilot Study}
    
\begin{threeparttable} 
\sisetup{table-format=13.0, table-number-alignment=center, table-column-width=1.0cm}
 \begin{tabular}{lSS}
 
     \toprule
     \textbf{Stimulus Number\tnote{a}} & \textbf{Classification Accuracy (\%)} \\ 
     

     \midrule
    Stimulus 1 (A21, B32; A11) &  68.42  \\
    Stimulus 2 (A2, B47; A1)  &   94.74 \\
    Stimulus 3 (A6, B40; B51)  &  84.21    \\
    Stimulus 4  (A5, B32; A4) &  100.00  \\
    Stimulus 5  (A16, B49; B50) & 100.00  \\
    Stimulus 6  (A7, B36; B37) & 84.21   \\
    Stimulus 7  (A20, B38; A21) & 100.00  \\ 
    Stimulus 8  (A29, B45; B46) & 100.00   \\
    Stimulus 9  (A24, B43; A26) & 100.00 \\
    Stimulus 10 (A11, B50; B51) & 94.74   \\ 
    Stimulus 11 (A8, B35; B36) & 100.00  \\
    Stimulus 12 (A10, B42; B43) & 100.00   \\
    Stimulus 13 (A8, B32; A10) & 100.00    \\
    Stimulus 14 (A18, B34; B35) & 89.47    \\ 
    Stimulus 15 (A3, B47; A23) & 94.74   \\
    Stimulus 16 (A13,  B38; A14) & 84.21    \\
    Stimulus 17 (A18, B43; A21)& 68.42    \\
    Stimulus 18 (A7, B40; B42) & 84.21    \\ 
    Stimulus 19 (A23, B47; A24) & 94.74      \\
    Stimulus 20 (A8, B55; B56) & 89.47     \\

 \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \footnotesize 
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] Stimulus Number (Class A Sample Numbers, Class B Sample Numbers; Reference X Sample Numbers)
\end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable} 
\end{table}   


\end{document}
```

Comment: Which version of `siunitx` do you employ? When I run your code on my system (MacTeX2021, siunitx 2021-08-04 v3.0.24), I get a rather different-looking result.